# Why is: dict() reducing the length of the list when both list have same length?

Tags: python-3.x

I used dict(zip(list1, list2)) both list have a length of 211 but after dict(zip(list1,list2))
the length of the dictionary is 185. There is no duplicate value, why is there a drop in length and how to fix it so that the dict length is 211

Comment: Can you please show some values of both list

Comment: are you sure there are no duplicates and each lists hvae same length?  try converting `list` to `set` then check the length

Comment: oh after converting to set, I realised 1 of the list got duplicates oops. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should first amend your question to give more details (e.g. sample of the two lists, code used, etc.)

Nevertheless, the problem is quite obvious - you have duplicate keys in they key list, that is:

```
key_list = ['a', 'b', 'a'] #the duplicate key 'a'
value_list = [1, 2, 3]
d = dict(zip(key_list, value_list)) #d = {'a': 3, 'b': 2}
```